# What attack does the Wizard do when attacking with a spell while out of Arcane Power?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I've noticed that if my Wizard runs out of Arcane Power while I'm spamming an ability that costs arcane power, I start shooting little white dots at the enemy which do damage. This surprised me because I would have expected it to default to my primary ability, which doesn't cost any Arcane Power, when I run out of the shiney purple stuff

What attack is this?

Not sure if it matters, but I usually equip wands, so perhaps it's a wand attack? If it is a weapon auto-attack, is this a wand-specific attack or a wizard-specific attack? For example, if I equip a sword instead of a wand, will I start swinging my weapon instead of shooting dots?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is the basic weapon attack.  When you start out a level 1 character, it's the skill that is on right mouse button.  With wands it's a small projectile, with swords you would run up to the monster and slash it.

You can also set this skill if you are in elective mode, and assign a skill to a hotkey when it is already assigned.  For instance, if you have Magic Missle assigned to left mouse, and decide to remap it to right mouse, you will get the default weapon attack set to your left mouse button.

Comment: Do you know if that attack is specific to the wizard, or to the weapon I am using? For example, if I equip a sword, will I start doing sword attacks instead of shooting bullets?

Comment: I haven't tried a non-wand attack specifically with the wizard, but I'm fairly sure it's the weapon attack.  On my monk it causes me to actually stab things with my spears, or swing a dagger.

Comment: @Rachel: Yes, you will swing with your melee weapon if you have one equipped. This has the side effect of causing you to run towards your target to do so, which may not be desirable. :)

Comment: @adamjford Definitely not desirable... I die fast enough as it is and have no intentions of getting closer to those monsters! :)

Comment: In those cases, shift+click will keep you from moving (even if you run out of Arcane Power and have a non-ranged weapon).

Answer (score 0):

It's your main weapon attack, in your case, the wand.

Answer (score 0):

The basic attack also depends on what weapon you have.  If you have a wand, you'll do the ranged attack.  But I noticed while using melee weapons like a sword or a spear, if you're out of energy and you try to use the spell, your character will actually start running towards the enemy to do a melee attack.

This can be dangerous when you're trying to kite a mob and instead your character starts running towards them instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you are out of mana, you do regain mana slowly but if you do not select your generator spell and try to cast a spell outside of your current mana bank - **you will cast your wand by default.**

Whatever the users's spell that is bound to their left click **BY DEFAULT is their generator spell**.   Your signature spells are free to cast. ( 4 main spells )
*Such as magic missile, electrocute, etc.*

Comment: It's definitely not any of my 4 primary attacks (Magic Missile, Electrocute, Shock Pulse, or Spectral Blade)

Comment: @Rachel Please see edit if it makes more sense?  I can source this if needed.... I don't know why there is down votes on this answer.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks. Your original wording made it sound like you were saying if a Wizard ran out of Arcane Power then they would start casting their generator spell, which is incorrect.